# Python / PyQt4 memory leak

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm writing a kiosk-style slideshow Python (2.7) & PyQt4 program that essentially reads a directory filled with with jpeg images then displays them fading from image to image,etc. There's a memory leak somewhere and I'm pretty sure it's in the fade process. My fade process is based on the technique defined here:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Fading%20Between%20Widgets

Except instead of the QCalendarWidget and QTextEdit I use two QGraphicsViews.

In an effort to address the memory leak, I modified the following:

```
painter = QPainter()
```

to one defined in FaderWidget's __init __() that's created once:

```
self.painter = QPainter()
```

More recently, I tried using valgrind to help debug this. I've tried both:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck python foo.py
valgrind --leak-check=full python foo.py
```

but unsure how to effectively interpret and use the data it returns.
The first use of valgrind returned:

```
==22436== HEAP    SUMMARY:
==22436==     in use at exit: 419,841,996 bytes in 58,236 blocks
==22436==   total heap usage: 890,500 allocs, 832,264 frees, 1,159,349,520 bytes allocated
==22436==
==22436== LEAK SUMMARY:
==22436==    definitely lost: 14,518 bytes in 54 blocks
==22436==    indirectly lost: 50,006 bytes in 1,476 blocks
==22436==      possibly lost: 117,696 bytes in 317 blocks
==22436==    still reachable: 419,659,776 bytes in 56,389 blocks
==22436==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
```

Lastly, the images in each of the QGraphicsView() are loaded like so:

```
self.path1      = self.imageList[self.count]
self.pixImage1  = QtGui.QImage(self.path1)
self.pixNormal1 = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.pixImage1)
self.pixScaled1 = self.pixNormal1.scaled( self.PixFrame.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
```

Is it possible that the QImage() and QPixmap() calls are not being garbage collected and are accumulating?

Would anyone have any thoughts or suggestions about how to address this?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think there is a memory leak? Why do you think it is caused by QPainter? Why do you abuse creating attributes of the class? For the latter, it is necessary to take the QImage as an attribute, why do you use QImage if QPixmap can do the work directly and worse, make it a member of the class?

Comment: The reason I think there's a memory leak is twofold. One, the computer bogs down and becomes essential hung. Exiting the program returns system to something close to normal but I reboot anyways. And two, I used Python's 'resource' module to see how memory is increasing as I use the program: >>> import resource

>>> resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss

Comment: okay, 
How do you add the images to QGraphicsView?

Comment: self.main.scene1.addPixmap(self.main.pixScaled1)

Comment: there is the problem

Comment: Ahh, so should I clear() the associated QGraphicsScene() of the QGraphicsView ?

Comment: Doh, I'm doing that already.

Comment: The problem is that you are creating a QGraphicsPixmapItem every time when using addPixmap(), what you must do is create an empty one and add it to the scene, and then just reuse it using the setPixmap() method of QGraphicsPixmapItem.

Comment: do not call clear(), I'm consuming a lot of resources, just reuse the QGraphicsPixmapItem

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and report my results.

Comment: Do not use `self` indiscriminately, every time you use it you will keep the data in memory, for example the path is not necessary, the creation of the QImage is unnecessary, making the class attribute to the QPixmap is also unnecessary `path      = self.imageList[self.count]
pix = QtGui.QPixmap(path).scaled(self.PixFrame.size(), QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio, QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)
self.your_QGraphicsPixmapItem.setPixmap(pìx)`

Comment: Yes, I was aware of those things but chose to prototype rather loosely for now and plan on optimizing later.  Thanks

Comment: Do not complain about memory now if you do not take it into account now. :)

Comment: So turns out that my previous version that clear()'d the scene, then added a new Pixmap is equivalent in memory consumption to your solution of not clear()'ing and re-using the same PixmapItem.  I found the source of the memory leak though and it did indeed lie in the Fader class' setCurrentIndex() function.  I should've spotted that before, but refactoring the self.fader_widget = FaderWidget() call into init() fixed the issue.  Now as I go from image to image, memory stats stay the same.  Thank you.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to un-mark this as a duplicate post, since the solution you offered, while appreciated, did not solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: It is a duplicate because the error is caused by not reusing, that is what both questions teach us, on the other hand your current question could never be answered as they are, and instead of helping cause confusion. Your current question is A and B, and your solution is Z, that is, the problem is not visible in your question.

Comment: On the contrary, I stated early on in the first couple of sentences the Fader() class connection and concern.

Comment: What you pointed out or try to redirect is the Fader implementation itself, but as you point out the problem is not there, but you have created many Faders indiscriminately

Comment: On the contrary, I sought help on a memory leak that I suspected originated in the link provided.  Indeed that turned out to be the case.